# How to extract and sum columns from CSV files with Python?

Tags: python, linux, csv

I have a particular kind of CSV file whose format is kinda like follows (I extracted just those columns from a network log with the help of Linux AWK):

```
SourceIP=10.0.0.1,DestIP=11.0.0.1,InputBytes=120,OutputBytes=2450
SourceIP=10.0.0.1,DestIP=11.0.1.1,InputBytes=450,OutputBytes=110
SourceIP=10.0.0.2,DestIP=11.0.2.2,InputBytes=180,OutputBytes=0
SourceIP=10.0.0.3,DestIP=13.0.7.1,InputBytes=20175,OutputBytes=15314
SourceIP=10.0.0.1,DestIP=19.0.1.1,InputBytes=350151,OutputBytes=1501
SourceIP=10.0.0.2,DestIP=45.0.12.1,InputBytes=2400,OutputBytes=21450
SourceIP=10.0.0.2,DestIP=47.10.0.1,InputBytes=74510,OutputBytes=850
SourceIP=10.0.0.1,DestIP=11.0.0.1,InputBytes=37581,OutputBytes=3250
SourceIP=10.0.0.3,DestIP=11.0.0.1,InputBytes=1300,OutputBytes=67
SourceIP=10.0.0.1,DestIP=11.0.1.1,InputBytes=45010,OutputBytes=1120
```

I need to receive as argument a given Source IP address, for example "10.0.0.1", then sum (separately) the total of InputBytes (and print them), then total of OutputBytes (then print them) **for each DestIP**. Ideally The desired output would be something like:

```
>file.py log.csv 10.0.0.1

10.0.0.1 connected to 19.0.1.1 with 350151 InputBytes
10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.1.1 with 45460 InputBytes
10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.0.1 with 37701 InputBytes

10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.0.1 with 5700 OutputBytes
10.0.0.1 connected to 19.0.1.1 with 1501 OutputBytes
10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.1.1 with 1230 OutputBytes
```

Some observations:

1. It is safe to assume that all four original fields will appear.
2. The thing about the output would (ideally) be for each group (InputBytes and OutputBytes separately) to be sort in order since the idea is to identify what DestIP address received/sent more information.
3. Unfortunately I don't have a code to start with (I'm just getting familiarized with file reading though)

Any help is heartly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably pre-process the file. You can parse it as a CSV & then parse each value from `SourceIP=10.0.0.1` to extract just the IP. Then build a table (you can use a numpy array) from it. Then summing up the columns for a source IP should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

big_d = defaultdict(dict)

with open("tmp.csv") as f:
        for j, line in enumerate(f):
                attr = line.split(',')
                d = {}
                for a in attr:
                        key, val = a.split('=')
                        d[key] = val
                try:
                        big_d[d['SourceIP']][d['DestIP']]['in']  += int(d['InputBytes'])
                        big_d[d['SourceIP']][d['DestIP']]['out'] += int(d['InputBytes'])
                except:
                        big_d[d['SourceIP']][d['DestIP']] = {'in' : int(d['InputBytes']), 'out':int(d['InputBytes']),}

input_ip = sys.argv[1]

for dest_ip in big_d[input_ip]:
        print input_ip, "connected to", dest_ip, "with", big_d[input_ip][dest_ip]['in'], "InputBytes"
        print input_ip, "connected to", dest_ip, "with", big_d[input_ip][dest_ip]['out'], "OutputBytes"
```

output:

> ~ python tmp.py 10.0.0.1
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.0.1 with 37701 InputBytes 
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.0.1 with 37701 OutputBytes 
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.1.1 with 45460 InputBytes 
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 11.0.1.1 with 45460 OutputBytes
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 19.0.1.1 with 350151 InputBytes
> 10.0.0.1 connected to 19.0.1.1 with 350151 OutputBytes\

tmp.csv is your input file.
I believe it does everything you ask for.